# How can I efficiently create variants of a conditional?

Tags: conditionals, expl3

Say I have the following:

```
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \sean_cond:n { T,F,TF } { \prg_return_false: }
```

How can I efficiently create the following?  (This list is arbitrary.)

```
\sean_cond:nT \sean_cond:nF \sean_cond:nTF
\sean_cond:oT \sean_cond:oF \sean_cond:oTF
\sean_cond:VT \sean_cond:VF \sean_cond:VTF
```

I know I could (probably) use something like the following, but I feel like that's harder than it needs to be.

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sean_cond:nT { o, V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sean_cond:nF { o, V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \sean_cond:nTF { o, V }
```

Comment: Some time ago I heard some discussion about `\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nn`, but I don't know where that ended.

Comment: @Manuel I imagine it would need to be `:Nnn`, though: `\…:Nnn\sean_cond:n{o,V}{T,F,TF}`

Comment: Not necessarily, if you define a conditional with only `{ T , TF }`, then the system “knows” it, and you just need `\···:Nn \sean_cond:n { o , V }`. But, in any case, I don't know where that discussion ended.

Comment: @Manuel Oooh, nifty. For the record, [here is the discussion you're remembering](http://listserv.uni-heidelberg.de/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1409&L=latex-l&D=0&P=4590).

Comment: That's the way to go: you have to tell what functions you want a variant of. Of course, `\sean_cond:nT` and `\sean_cond:nF` are defined in terms of `\sean_cond:nTF`, but this is unimportant as long as variants are concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The December 2017 release of `expl3` added

```
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn
```

that simplifies the definition of variants.

Here's the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \sean_cond:n { T, F, TF } { \prg_return_false: }

\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \sean_cond:n { o, V } { T, F, TF }

\cs_show:N \sean_cond:nT
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:nF
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:nTF
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:oT
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:oF
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:oTF
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:VT
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:VF
\cs_show:N \sean_cond:VTF

\stop
```

All nine functions will be defined.